# Was ist korrekt?

Tags: grammar-identification

Was ist korrekt beim Sprechen?

Heute spreche ich zum Thema Adoption? oder 
Heute werde ich zum Thema Adoption sprechen?

Ich bitte um die Erklärung dieser Problematik. Danke

Comment: Welche Probleme möchtest du, dass sie erklärt werden? Die Frage ist unklar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Heute spreche ich zum Thema Adoption.

Das ist **Präsens**. Da **heute** im Satz vorkommt, bezieht sich die Gegenwart auf eben dieses *heute*. Es muss also nicht jetzt sofort mit dem Vortrag losgehen, es reicht, wenn es *heute* passiert:

> Heute spreche ich zum Thema Adoption, aber erst nach dem Essen.

Das funktioniert genauso gut mit **morgen**:

> Morgen spreche ich zum Thema Adoption.

Man muss im Deutschen das *Futur* also nicht benutzen. Wenn man ohnehin eine Zeitangabe im Satz oder auch nur im Kontext hat, tut es auch das *Präsens*.

---

> Heute werde ich zum Thema Adoption sprechen.

Das ist **Futur I**. Auch richtig. Die Betonung der Zukunft heißt oft, dass es nicht unmittelbar im Anschluss losgeht. Viele Redner nutzen das als Stilmittel, um eine längere Einleitung anzukündigen:

> Heute werde ich zum Thema Adoption sprechen. Aber erst einmal erkläre ich etwas Grundsätzliches über das sogenannte *Kindswohl*.